# Strip HTML from a directory containing .txt files with PERL

Tags: perl

I'm a complete n00b.  I've read many of the other posts on this site and I haven't been able to figure out a solution to this relatively simple problem.  Basically, I have a directory of text files that are marked up with HTML.  I want to strip the HTML from each of the files in this directory and then export each individual file to a new text files (preferably with the _out.txt extention).  Here is what I've tried so far:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;
use HTML::FormatText;


my $root_path=qq{C:\\Filings\\test}; #Declare your input path
# Recursively it process all the sub directories in $root_path
find(\&process_multiple_dir, $root_path);
sub process_multiple_dir
{
    if (-f && $File::Find::name =~ m{\.txt$}) # It process .txt format files only
    {
          undef $/; # Input Record separator
          # Files Handling process
          open (FIN, "<$File::Find::name") || die "Cannot Open the Input file";
          my $file=<FIN>; # Assign the file handler to scalar variable
          #print $file;

          my $string = HTML::FormatText->format_file($file,leftmargin => 0, rightmargin => 50);
          #print $string;
          close (FIN);
          # Change the file name for the output file creation purpose
          $File::Find::name=~ s{\.txt}{_Out.txt};


          # Print the $file contents to new file
          open (FOUT, ">$File::Find::name") || die "Cannot Create the Output file";
          print FOUT $string;
          close (FOUT);
      }
}
```

This code will output a file with the new file name (the _out.txt extention tagged on), but the newly created file has no text in it...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use HTML::FormatText myself, but i think the correct syntax is:

```
my $string = HTML::FormatText->format_file($File::Find::name,leftmargin => 0, rightmargin => 50);
```

So no need to open the file and slurp it into `$file`.

(PS: use some indentation in your code; it makes it much more readable :) )

Comment: Glad to help; if you're happy with an answer, it is customary to accept such answer...

Comment: Sorry--as I said before--I'm a n00b...thanks for reminding me that I needed to accept the answer.  This helped in the context of this program, I started the other question because I completely revamped and rewrote the program...however...as some have hinted...this one might just be better...